# MySQL execute every query on a second server

Tags: mysql, backup, query

I have a Web-application on a Linux Debian 8 Server saving in MySQL.

I need a backup which is always the latest version(not even a minute behind) so the only way i could think off to archive this is to execute every Query on a second MySQL server with identical database

Is there a way to do this without my Application having to handle this?

Comment: Have you checked MySQL Proxy (from oracle) and SQL Relay http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/documentation.html. Both can be setup in a way to send the query to a second server.

Comment: unfortunately it is not available for Debian, but "Query Routing" mentioned is exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: what about mysql replication?

Comment: then i had to read from the slave and insert into the master but i cant "touch" the application

Comment: if you are careful - you can have master/master replication. also maybe proxysql can help, though it probably is not available with debian packages